# PHPMailer send embeded imagea long with body text

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send emails. I need to send embed images along with the text. So, I am using this:

```
mail->isHTML(true);//Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = $email_subject;
$mail->Body    = "<img src='$url'>";
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($url,'greetingcard','greetingcard.'.$extension);
$mail->Body = $email_body;
$mail->Body = '<img src="cid:greetingcard">';
$mail->send();
```

the variable `$email_body` contains the body text. Now, the embed image is showing but the body text is not showing on the email. Can you tell me why?

Comment: You would need to append to `Body` instead of reassigning it multiple times (something like `$mail->Body .= "..."`) ✌

Comment: OH, my big mistake, let me check :)